# What does unique records mean in GetStream?

Tags: getstream-io

In the [getstream](https://getstream.io/pricing/) pricing page it is mentioned that the Free plan has 600,000 unique records. Is there any section in dashboard where I can see how many unique records I have used?

Also can I know what does a unique record means exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unique records are all activities and feeds.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, is there anywhere i can see how many unique records are there thus far?

Comment: Yes, go into the dashboard, click on feeds at the top and then usage.